# Clojure app not starting on Heroku; Aleph + RedisToGo timing out

Tags: clojure, heroku

My clojure noir app works 100% fine locally and connects to RedisToGo no problem.

The problem is when I deploy to Heroku (git push heroku master), I get a timeout error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Full log is here: https://gist.github.com/1842439

When I remove this redis connection code, it deploys fine:

```
(:use [aleph.redis :only (redis-client)])    
(def r (redis-client {:host redis-url :password redis-pass :port redis-port}))
```

The weird thing is that when I run "heroku run lein run repl" and paste in the aleph code above, it connects to redis fine and I can read/write data.

So it something about how heroku boots up the app thats breaking the connection to RedisToGo and timing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing something side-effecty at the top level is very suspect - that code is executed when compiling as well as when executing, so probably the automatic uberjar Heroku does is failing because redis isn't available at compile time, or something like that.

Instead, initialize your redis client after `-main` has been called, which will ensure you are in a production environment. You can accomplish this in a number of ways, for example by initially defining it to nil and then performing an `alter-var-root` in `-main`. My preferred solution would probably be something like:

```
(def r (delay (redis-client ...)))
(defn get-stuff []
  (let [client @r] ...))
(defn -main [& args]
  (get-stuff)
  ...)
```

Now the code to connect isn't performed until someone derefs the client, which they should never do until the app is up and running.

Comment: Yeah I just tried adding a delay to the redis connection and tested deployment, had the same timeout issue. The commit: https://github.com/dmix/documeds/commit/2aca28bb228c36374e5a21bccbb774438bc1c223

Comment: Not that it matters, but why are you defining `r` twice? Your program may be an exception, but it seems like most of the time you want a shared client across your app (although you should probably make sure it's not shared across threads)

Comment: Further attempts at deploying the fixed to delaying the process seemed to fix the issue. I'm defining the redis client separately for the scraper since it will be executed in isolation in the future.